# Enforce short delay between DB update and implicit COMMIT in ABAP?

Tags: commit, abap

As a SAP infrastructure department, sometimes we encounter a problem within SAP AS (`NW` / `S/4`) when a `WP` is making a write access to DB, therefore a record is being locked until an explicit `COMMIT` command is made. However, in some cases developers aren't explicitly calling `COMMIT` (inattentiveness, laziness) thus the record is being locked until an implicit `COMMIT` is made. That cause other `WP`s modifying the same record to get stuck for a while (in some cases - until timeout is reached).

We are trying to find a mechanism to recognize such a pattern, at least to monitor the existing situation in production, and preferably to intercept it in the early stages of application development life-cycle.

Static code checks don't seem to be an option:

1. There might be justifications to not explicitly `COMMIT` every DB write access (I.E: Write access being called in `ON_COMMIT` event.
2. Queries may reside in functions/methods which called from a process that take care of the commit itself.

We tried to find a relevant monitoring item under `RZ20`, and didn't find any.

Reproduce:

```
REPORT zfirst.
DATA: ls_scarr TYPE scarr.
ls_scarr-carrid = 'TST'.
MODIFY scarr FROM ls_scarr.
DO. ENDDO.

REPORT zsecond.
ls_scarr-carrid = 'TST'.
MODIFY scarr FROM ls_scarr.
```

Run `zfirst`, it runs forever due to the `DO` loop. let it stuck. Then Run `zsecond`. it will stuck in the MODIFY line.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can detect basic infinitive loops with code analyzer. But these loops already founded and fixed in test step.

DB locks is a completely design problem. Architect needs to plan the solution for thinking about parallel updates (if needed).

You can get list of locks under DB01 t-code Locks section.

I want to add some notes here:

- Developer can use locking mechanism for table lines.
- Developer can call `commit work` manually if there is not need to rollback.

Comment: Small addition: DB01 > Diagnostics > Locks > Blocked Transactions also shows that "zsecond" is blocked by "zfirst" for the example the OP provided.